# Threading issue - UI updates before the webservice has finished

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin.android

I've searched for examples on how to fix
the problem below, but can't seem to find what I need and it's starting to
drive me potty!

Essentially, I have a race condition whereby the webservice is finishing way
after return has been given to the UI, so the UI is not displaying anything
at all.

Here's the code. The webservice does actually get the correct data which is
the pain of it all! The `generateNewScreen` method comes as a result of
clicking some text on a ListView area.

**Calling routine**

```
private void generateNewScreen(int t)
{
    string[] races = new string[] { };
    View currentview = FindViewById<View>(Resource.Id.relLayout);
    TextView text = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textTitle);
    ListView listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView);
    ImageView image = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgBack);
    image.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

    Console.WriteLine("t = {0}, addFactor = {1}", t,addFactor);

    switch (addFactor)
    {
        case 0: 
            switch (t)
            {
                case 0: races =listviewInfo(Resource.Array.RaceTracks,
                    Resource.Drawable.Back_RaceHorsePlace, Resource.String.Tracks);
                    addFactor = 10;
                    break;

                case 1: List<string> 
                    race = new List<string>();                                                  
                    currentview.SetBackgroundDrawable(Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.Back_BobMoore));
                    text.Text = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.ComingSoon);
                    webservice_user getRace = new webservice_user();
                    race = getRace.getUpcomingRaces("RP");
                    races = race.ToArray();
                    addFactor = 20;
                    break;
            }

            if (t < 6 || t == 7)
                listView.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Resource.Layout.listview_layout, races);
            break;
    }
}
```

**Webservice**

```
private string rTrack;

public List<string> getUpcomingRaces(string track)
{
    List<string> f = new List<string>();
    rTrack = track;
    getUpcomingRacesCallBack((list) =>
    {
        f = list;
    });
    return f;
}

private void getUpcomingRacesCallBack(Action<List&lt;string>> callback)
{
    List<string> f = new List<string>();

    if (checkForNetwork(true) != true)
    {
        f.Add("No network available");
        callback(f);
    }
    else
    {
        List<POHWS.webservice.UpcomingRaces> tableData = new List<POHWS.webservice.UpcomingRaces>();
        POHWS.webservice.Service1 Service3 = new POHWS.webservice.Service1();
        try
        {
            Service3.BeginGetUpcomingRacesList(rTrack, delegate(IAsyncResult iar)
            {
                tableData = Service3.EndGetUpcomingRacesList(iar).ToList();
                Android.App.Application.SynchronizationContext.Post(delegate
                {
                    if (tableData.Count == 0)
                    {
                        f.Add("No Upcoming Races Found within the next 7 days");
                        callback(f);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < tableData.Count;++i)
                            f.Add(tableData[i].PostTime);
                        callback(f);
                    }
                }, null);
            }, null);
        }
        catch (Exception oe)
        {
            f.Add(oe.ToString());
            callback(f);
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to either stop the UI or delay updating until the webservice
has done what it needs? I've tried quite a lot of things, but nothing gives.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `getUpcomingRaces()` is acting as if the call to `getUpcomingRacesCallBack()` is synchronous, and returns the list right away. Since it's very unlikely that the lambda would have fired before the return statement, it is always going to return the empty list.

I would suggest restructuring the code so that it acts on the list only once it's returned, similar to the approach you took with the `getUpcomingRacesCallBack()` method, which takes in an `Action<List<string>>`.

If it helps, I have a sample project [available here](https://github.com/gshackles/Sample-Projects/tree/master/MonoDroid/TwitterSearcher) that shows how to use this pattern. I also have a [post here](http://www.gregshackles.com/2011/04/using-background-threads-in-mono-for-android-applications/) that talks about some different approaches to doing work off the UI thread, just in case you end up going the route of making the calls synchronous.